# How to make a link inside a list item take the whole list item space?

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to make a link in a list item always take up 100% of the width and height of the list item no matter the screen size?

```
.navList {
  list-style-type: none;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.navListItem {
  float: left;
}

.navListLink:link, .navListLink:visited {
  color: #000000;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 100%;
  display: block;
  padding: 1em;
}
```

Comment: Can you show your HTML.

Answer (score 1):

I have written this little code to show you how I would do it.

```
<style>
    ul{
        background-color: orange;
        width: 78%;
        height: 8rem;

        /* Centered on Viewport*/
        position: absolute;
        top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0;
        margin: auto;

        padding: 1rem;
    }
    li{            
        outline: thin solid white;
        list-style: none;
        font: 1.2rem/2rem Serif;
    }
    a{
        box-sizing: border-box;
        background-color: #444;
        display: inline-block;
        width: 100%;
        padding: 0 1rem; 
        color: white;        
    }
    a:link{
        text-decoration: none;
    }
</style>

<ul>
    <li><a href="#">item 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">item 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">item 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">item 4</a></li>
</ul>
```

I hope it helps you.

Comment: Awesome, thank you very much! I'm gonna see if I can apply this to my code thank you!

Comment: keep it simple ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use flex to adjust your link to its parent with the `stretch` value of the `align-items` property. That seems to me the least hacky way to do it.

Comment: Thank you! I guess I'll have to try and hack it together haha